# Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: unicode

I'm getting this error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...45}{martedì\relax }{figure.caption.21}{}}
```

martedì.png is the name of the file (actually was, since I renamed it) and I get the same error for all files containing an accent.

This is the line where I get the error in the .aux file:

```
\newlabel{fig:marted\IeC {\`\i }}{{15a}{45}{martedì\relax }{figure.caption.21}{}}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: you do not make it very easy for anyone to help. But this is made by a bad `\label` command (that you have not shown) it is best to only use `a-z, 0-9` in label arguments. You have used some active character or a command that produced `\relax`

Comment: Don't use accented letters in labels. You apparently did `\label{martedì}`: you can't. Well, in principle `\label{\detokenize{martedì}}` and `\ref{\detokenize{martedì}}` would work, but…

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I removed accents from figures labels and captions and solved the problem. 

The (funny) thing is that I now included the file into my main one while before, when compiling it as a document itself I didn't have any issue. 

Please answer the question so that the I could tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made by a bad `\label` command (that you have not shown) it is best to only use a-z, 0-9 in label arguments. You have used some active character or a command that produced `\relax`, most likely `\label{martedì}`